# How to loop over a list in a data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to loop over a data frame column which contains several lists and control if the values in the lists are countained by another data frame column.

I am pretty new to python and have this problem now for a longer time. I already tried to find a way to solve this problem with `isin` and `str.contains`, but I still got no match.

Here is the code I worked out so far:

```
data = [['yellow', 10,0], ['red', 15,0], ['blue', 14,0]] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Colour', 'Colour_id','Amount'])
df1

 Colour  Colour_id   Amount
 yellow  10          0
 red     15          0
 blue    14          0

data = [['tom',[10,15],200 ], ['adam', [10],50], ['john',[15,14],200]] 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Colour', 'Colour_id','Amount'])
df2 

 Name   Colour_id   Amount
 tom    [10,15]     200
 adam   [10]        50
 john   [15,14]     200


for indices, row in df2.iterrows():
    for i in row['Colour_id']:
        if i in df1['Colour_id']:
            df1['Amount']=df1['Amount']=df2['Amount']
        else:
            print("No")
```

The expect result should be that the Amount Column of df1 is filled like:

```
Colour  Colour_id   Amount
 yellow  10          250
 red     15          400
 blue    14          200
```

At the moment I only get the "No" of the else condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is create Series by convert list column to `DataFrame`, reshape by `stack` and aggregate `sum` and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2['Colour_id'].values.tolist(), index=df2['Amount']).stack().reset_index()
s = df3.groupby(0)['Amount'].sum()

df1['Amount'] = df1['Colour_id'].map(s)
print (df1)
   Colour  Colour_id  Amount
0  yellow         10     250
1     red         15     400
2    blue         14     200
```

Or use `defaultdict` with pure python fo dictionary by summing values and `map` for new column:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for cid, Amount in zip(df2['Colour_id'], df2['Amount']):
    for x in cid:
        d[x] += Amount

print (d)
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {10: 250, 15: 400, 14: 200})

df1['Amount'] = df1['Colour_id'].map(s)
print (df1)
   Colour  Colour_id  Amount
0  yellow         10     250
1     red         15     400
2    blue         14     200
```